# jQuery run when assets load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big image which is full width and full height, I have a jQuery script with document.ready but the script runs still before the image is loaded. Can I prepare the statement in another way so the image loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var currWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(currWidth);

var startPos = -100;
var endPos = (currWidth / 2) + (startPos / 2);
console.log(endPos);
$('#welcome').animate({left: endPos}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KtUEL/151/

Answer (score 0):

$(window).load(function() {

This instead of document.ready this fully loads the dom and all assets document.ready just loads the page.

thanks!

Solved

Comment: To clarify; `$(document).ready(function)` or just `$(function)` runs when the DOM has loaded, `$(window).load(function)` runs when the load event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as part of the html of your image via the onload event:

```
<img src="..." onload="myFunction()" />
```

This will trigger myFunction when that particular image is loaded rather than when the entire page has loaded.